# What is this spinning pokeball icon in the corner?

Tags: pokemon-go

I keep seeing this icon (looks like an icon that its loading something) and don't know what it means.

[image]

Using the app in Canada (where its not officially out yet) if that helps.

Comment: Yes it is, Tried to find the question and couldn't

Answer (score -1):

It means it's loading in general.

Comment: Fact is, I dont think it was ever not there. So what is it loading?

Comment: the ball spins whenever the app is talking to the server about something. And yes, the game talks to the server *constantly*

Comment: Your internet is probably slow or something. I get it only when I first login to the app, by the time the map renders the icon is gone.